# How does Jungle testnet create new account?

Tags: smart-contract, account-name, testnet

I have created new account in https://monitor.jungletestnet.io .

I have a copy of the log

```
# eosio <= eosio::newaccount {"creator":"junglefaucet","name":"myaccount","owner":{"threshold":1,"keys":[{"key":"EOS6gSJdxsQyD... 
#
# eosio <= eosio::buyrambytes {"payer":"junglefaucet","receiver":"myaccount","bytes":4096} 
#
# eosio.token <= eosio.token::transfer {"from":"junglefaucet","to":"eosio.ram","quantity":"3.6953 EOS","memo":"buy ram"} 
# junglefaucet <= eosio.token::transfer {"from":"junglefaucet","to":"eosio.ram","quantity":"3.6953 EOS","memo":"buy ram"} 
# eosio.ram <= eosio.token::transfer {"from":"junglefaucet","to":"eosio.ram","quantity":"3.6953 EOS","memo":"buy ram"} 
#
# eosio.token <= eosio.token::transfer {"from":"junglefaucet","to":"eosio.ramfee","quantity":"0.0186 EOS","memo":"ram fee"} 
# junglefaucet <= eosio.token::transfer {"from":"junglefaucet","to":"eosio.ramfee","quantity":"0.0186 EOS","memo":"ram fee"} 
# eosio.ramfee <= eosio.token::transfer {"from":"junglefaucet","to":"eosio.ramfee","quantity":"0.0186 EOS","memo":"ram fee"} 
#
# eosio.token <= eosio.token::transfer {"from":"eosio.ramfee","to":"eosio.rex","quantity":"0.0186 EOS","memo":"transfer from eosio.ramfee t... 
# eosio.ramfee <= eosio.token::transfer {"from":"eosio.ramfee","to":"eosio.rex","quantity":"0.0186 EOS","memo":"transfer from eosio.ramfee t... 
# eosio.rex <= eosio.token::transfer {"from":"eosio.ramfee","to":"eosio.rex","quantity":"0.0186 EOS","memo":"transfer from eosio.ramfee t... 
#
# eosio <= eosio::delegatebw {"from":"junglefaucet","receiver":"myaccount","stake_net_quantity":"1.0000 EOS","stake_cpu_quanti... 
#
# eosio.token <= eosio.token::transfer {"from":"junglefaucet","to":"eosio.stake","quantity":"2.0000 EOS","memo":"stake bandwidth"} 
# junglefaucet <= eosio.token::transfer {"from":"junglefaucet","to":"eosio.stake","quantity":"2.0000 EOS","memo":"stake bandwidth"} 
# eosio.stake <= eosio.token::transfer {"from":"junglefaucet","to":"eosio.stake","quantity":"2.0000 EOS","memo":"stake bandwidth"}
```

Now I want to create newaccount from command line using that account as a creator and got 
`account mynewaccount has insufficient ram; needs 2996 bytes has 0 bytes`
 error.

I have tried to buyram and buyrambytes, but failed since receiver does not exist yet.

How Jungle testnet create new accounts?

Answer (score 1):

So, I found the solution.
I have created text file containing all 3 actions: newaccount, buyrambytes and delegatebw. Provided all the data and called
`cleos push transaction filename.txt`

Here is my text file with the actual names replaced

```
{
  "actions": [
    {
      "account": "eosio",
      "name": "newaccount",
      "authorization": [
        {
          "actor": "youroldaccount",
          "permission": "active",
        }
      ],
      "data": {
        "creator": "youroldaccount",
        "name": "yournewaccount",
        "owner": {
          "threshold": 1,
          "keys": [
            {
              "key": "EOS5dnEvymnZUscQojaUGz2RyaF3ojhQKbVjjg9ZoE4hGY9K84yoc",
              "weight": 1,
            }
          ],
          "accounts": [],
          "waits": [],
        },
        "active": {
          "threshold": 1,
          "keys": [
            {
              "key": "EOS5dnEvymnZUscQojaUGz2RyaF3ojhQKbVjjg9ZoE4hGY9K84yoc",
              "weight": 1,
            }
          ],
          "accounts": [],
          "waits": [],
        },
      },
    },
    {
      "account": "eosio",
      "name": "buyrambytes",
      "authorization": [
        {
          "actor": "youroldaccount",
          "permission": "active",
        },
      ],
      "data": {
        "payer": "youroldaccount",
        "receiver": "yournewaccount",
        "bytes": 4096,
      },
    },
    {
      "account": "eosio",
      "name": "delegatebw",
      "authorization": [
        {
          "actor": "youroldaccount",
          "permission": "active",
        },
      ],
      "data": {
        "from": "youroldaccount",
        "receiver": "yournewaccount",
        "stake_net_quantity": "1.0000 EOS",
        "stake_cpu_quantity": "1.0000 EOS",
        "transfer": true,
      }
    },
  ],
}
```

Comment: delegatebw is necessary ?

Answer (score 0):

for creating account on jungle testnet all you need a public and private key,go to jungle testnet and create new account it will ask for EOS public key and username,paste your public key and give a valid username of exactly 12 characters

Answer (score 0):

you need to buy ram for creating an account from your existing account. convert some liquid eos into ram bytes. 
To buyram use this code from commandline

`cleos system buyram youraccountname youraccountname "50.0000 EOS"`

you may also need to buy some cpu and net resources for making any transaction for that use

`cleos system delegatebw youraccountname youraccountname "20.0000 EOS" "20.0000 EOS"`

Comment: Thank you for the response, I knew that I would need that steps besides creating new account. I mean buying RAM and delegating bandwidth. But, In your examples you're buying and delegating to the same account. we need to buy RAM for newaccount and delegate net/cpu to newaccount.
Actually I just succeeded to do what I wanted, I'll write the answer shortly. I need some experiments.